# Conditional distribution of sum of squared iid uniforms

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Is it true, that if $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ are iid uniform distributed variables on $\left[-1,1\right]$, then the sum of $U_{1}^{2}$ and $U_{2}^{2}$ is still uniform distributed conditioned on the set that this sum is not greater than $1$? Other words:

$$X\dot{=}U_{1}^{2}+U_{2}^{2}|U_{1}^{2}+U_{2}^{2}\leq1\sim Uni\left[0,1\right]?$$

I've read this in a book and for first glance this hasn't been clear. I guess we have to compare some kind of “conditional charachteristic” functions to decide this question.

Comment: The distribution of $X$ can be computed directly, no?

Comment: You mean with convolution? I think yes, but it requires more efforts in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake in the question. $U_1$ and $U_2$ are uniform on $[-1,1]$. I correct it...

Comment: It doesn't matter whether $U_1$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ or $[-1,1]$, since the distribution of $U^2$ is the same.

Comment: ...but I guess it is also true when $U_1$ and $U_2$ are uniform on $[0,1]$, therefore it wasn't a big mistake.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, I didn't update the page and didn't see your reply.

Comment: You wrote "not less than 1" but your notation had $\le 1$; I changed the text to "not greater than 1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Let $U_1,U_2\sim U(0,1),Y_1 = U_1^2$, then $$f_Y(y_1)dy_1=f_U(u_1)du_1$$ $$f_Y(y_1)=f_U(u_1)\frac{du_1}{dy_1}=1\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{dy_1}{du_1}}=\frac{1}{2u_1}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y_1}},\quad 0< y_1\le 1$$

The density of $X=U_1^2+U_2^2$ is the convolution of $f_Y(y_1)$ with itself, and Wolfram alpha gives this [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Convolve%5B1%2F%282*Sqrt%5Bx%5D%29*Boole%5B0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1%5D%2C1%2F%282*Sqrt%5Bx%5D%29*Boole%5B0%3C%3Dx%3C%3D1%5D%2Cx%2Cy%5D), from which we can see that the density $f_X(x)$ is constant when $0\le x\le 1$.

$$f_X(x|x\le 1)=\frac{f_X(x)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)}{P(x\le 1)}=\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$$

Note: I would like to add that it doesn't matter whether $U_1$
is uniform on $[0,1]$ or $[−1,1]$. If $U_1$ is uniform on $[−1,1]$, then $|U_1|$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, so $U_1^2=|U_1|^2$ still has the same distribution.

Answer (score 8):

A geometric proof: after conditioning, $(U_1, U_2)$ is a point chosen uniformly at random from the unit disk.

So for $0 < x < 1$, the probability $P(U_1^2 + U_2^2 < x)$ is the area of a disk of radius $\sqrt{x}$ divided by the area of the unit disk.

That's $\pi (\sqrt{x})^2/\pi = x$, giving the result.

Comment: This answer is the "proof from the book" :^).